# WordPress: Remove checkout page Billing Email Required and Validation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a WooCommerce project and my client wants Billing Email Optional not Mandatory in checkout page. I've did this following steps but did not get any result.

**class-wc-countries.php** (did not work)

```
$address_fields['billing_email'] = array(
                'label'        => __( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ),
                'required'     => false, //default was TRUE
                'type'         => 'email',
                'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
                'validate'     => false, // default was array( 'email' )
                'autocomplete' => 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ? 'email' : 'email username',
                'priority'     => 110,
            );
```

also add this line of code in my child theme **function.php** (did not work)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'misha_no_email_validation' );
 
function misha_no_email_validation( $fields ){
 
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['required'] = false;
    unset( $fields['billing']['billing_email']['validate'] );
    
    return $fields;
 
}
```

then use 2 plugin **Checkout Field Editor for WooCommerce** and **Flexible Checkout Fields** but did not get any result.

[image]

Please help!!

Thanks.

Comment: Everything in WooCommerce works with email. Why removing it? You will not receive any mail about your order status or even the invoice, legals..

Comment: instead of email we are going to use mobile number, also we are going to use mobile api for order notification, order details etc. https://shop.shajgoj.com/ they are using email as optional.

Comment: Your code should be work try to change a priority.

Comment: @Bhautik I did but nothing happed

Comment: Try deactivating all plugins except woocommerce and check.

Comment: @Bhautik result same

Comment: I think then you need to debug more.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add priority of `20` to the `filter hook`. This works on my end! It'll make it `optional` with `no validation`.

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'misha_no_email_validation', 20);

function misha_no_email_validation($fields){

  $fields['billing']['billing_email']['required'] = false;

  return $fields;

}
```

Comment: @MarufAhmed Were you able to get my code to work?